# How to use "never" with Present simple tense

Tags: present-perfect, negation, present-tense, perfect-constructions

I learned that we could use "never" with present perfect tense about experiences in someone’s life. However, I don’t understand when we use never with other tenses like present simple tense.

I **never eat** avocados.

I **have never eaten** avocados.

Could you tell me that above sentences have the same meaning or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different meaning. *have never eaten* means you've never tried this fruit, you don't even know the taste. When *never eat* means you don't eat them, it is not your habit, I won't see avocados in your hands. But notice that if you *don't eat* them, it doesn't imply *you've never eaten* them. Maybe you used to eat them before, but then stopped.